# Retrieving the rows using join query

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables like this

```
A             B
----          -------       
col1  col2    col1   col2
----------    -----------
```

A table contains 300k rows
B table contains 400k rows

I need to count the col1 for table A if it is matching col1 for table B
I have written a query like this:

```
select count(distinct ab.col1) from A ab join B bc on(ab.col1=bc.col1)
```

but this takes too much time

Comment: please show `explain analyze` for your query

Answer (score 1):

could try a group by...
Also ensure that the col1 is indexed in both tables

```
SELECT COUNT (col1 )
FROM
(
SELECT aa.col1
FROM A aa JOIN B bb on aa.col1 = bb.col1
GROUP BY (aa.col1)
)
```

Comment: I created btree indexe on both columns

Comment: and also i tried your query ...it will also take too much time

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to answer without you positing more details: did you analyze the tables? Do you have an index on col1 on each table? How many rows are you counting?

That being said, there aren'y so many potential query plans for your query. You likely have two seq scans that are hash joined together, which is about the best you can do... If you've a material numbers of rows, you'll be counting a gazillion rows, and this takes time.

Perhaps you could rewrite the query differently? If every B.col1 is in A.col1, you could get the same result without the join:

```
select count(distinct col1) from B
```

If A has low cardinality, it might be faster to rely on exists():

```
with vals as (
  select distinct A.col1 as val from A
)
select count(*) from vals
where exists(select 1 from B where B.col1 = vals.val)
```

Or, if you know every possible value from A.col1 and it's reasonably small, you could unnest an array without querying A at all:

```
select count(*) from unnest(Array[val1, val2, ...]) as vals (val)
where exists(select 1 from B where B.col1 = vals.val)
```

Or vice-versa, in each of the above, if every B holds the reference values.

Comment: Per the answer, the various queries which are highlighted after the first two paragraphs will only yield the result you're looking for in very specific cases that depend on your schema and data.

Comment: Also, and btw, without posting the information that was requested at the beginning of my answer, there's little room to provide a better answer.