# how to count the distinct rows from two tables using joins

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables like

```
 table1                               table2
------------                     ----------------
col1    col2                      col1      col2
```

I need to count the distinct col1 from table1 if itis matching with table2 col1

note: table2 col1 also distinct

Comment: Duplicate of [Retrieving the rows using join query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19445462/retrieving-the-rows-using-join-query) (by the same author)

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(distinct table1.col1) 
from table1,table2 
where table1.col1=table2.col1
```

As you select the distinct col of table1, and set the join, the col1 of table2 will also be selected distinctly.

Comment: Please don't use implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause. Use explicit `JOIN`s in the `FROM` clause

Comment: but this query takes too much time i have created index also for both columns'

Comment: Then as a_horse_with_no_name suggests, use JOIN.